# KDB+ / Q Better webinterface

Tags: kdb

I am wondering if there is a html script with corresponding q script out there that brings a better webinterface (*than the basic builtin one*) with advanced functionality like

> - showing all namespaces (with option to unfold or browse into)
> - resolving foreign keys (with option to click on it and it will be opened in the table its refering to)
> - maybe even more stuff like dbadmin tools like phpmyadmin

Any tips where to find stuff like this or did it nobody implement yet?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [doth](http://code.kx.com/wsvn/code/contrib/simon/doth) package by simon? This is probably not even close to what you describe, but it could be a starting point to implement something [custom](http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/custom-web/).

Comment: Thats a great starting point to implement something by myself thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a good introduction to HTML5/websockets with Q in the TorQ framework by AquaQ Analytics: http://github.com/AquaQAnalytics/TorQ

Comment: Link is dead, can now be found at https://github.com/AquaQAnalytics/TorQ